# Connect Agile Carousel to WordPress AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax

Originally I hacked together Agile Carousel and WordPress by passing wp-load.php into the AJAX script but clearly that isn't the way to go. I've now read that wp-admin/admin-ajax.php is better, but I can't yet trigger the `add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_...')` method.

How can I find out what the action value is? Without knowing this, what other ways can I trigger a method that has access to all of WordPress' variables/functions?

Comment: Can you include the part of the javascript that makes the AJAX request?

Comment: The line in Agile Carousel that fetches the data is `$.getJSON("AJAX-URL", function(data) {`

Answer (score 1):

After some digging, I decided to try a hunch and it ended up working. Whether this is the sanctioned solution or not, but it has worked in my testing.

For the AJAX url, add the $_GET variable `?action=[ajax_action]` where [ajax_action] is your requested action. (ie. http://www.example.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=[ajax_action])

Then make `add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_...')` include your action variable, ie. `add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_[ajax_action]', 'ajax_callback')` and to make sure it works for logged in users, include `add_action('wp_ajax_[ajax_action]', 'ajax_callback')` as well.

I imagine that a similar solution would work for more generalized AJAX requests.

Answer (score 0):

That action value is whatever you define - just be sure to add the same action to the source URL for the Agile Carousel - something like that: `"AJAX-URL?action=carousel"` ... and the hook should look about like that:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_carousel', 'name_of_the_function_to_call_here');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_carousel', 'name_of_the_function_to_call_here');
```